# How to get attachment_url image by comment id on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, plugins

Hi i'm use plugin **DCO Comment Attachment** to be able to add images to comments, I use code below get list comments. Now I want to get the image link of the comment to handle before showing it to the screen. Currently according to the code below, it only takes all the image files attached to the comment post, not each comment.
I tried instead `$comment->comment_post_ID` to `$comment->comment_ID` but it does not work.
Thank everyone!

```
<?php $comments = get_comments($param);?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <?php if ($comment->comment_approved != '0'): ?>
        <?php
        $attachments = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'post_parent' => $comment->comment_post_ID,
        ));

        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
            }
        }
        ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After self-study, I know how to get the url image in the comment with the following code, this code put in the functions.php file.

```
function get_attachment_url_image_comment($comment_id) {
    $meta_key = 'attachment_id';
    $attachment_id = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, $meta_key, true );
    $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    return $full_img_url;
}
```

All that's left to do is pass the desired comment ID into the function and get the attached image

```
<?php $comments = get_comments($param);?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <?php if ($comment->comment_approved != '0'): ?>
       
          <?php if(get_attachment_url_image_comment($comment->comment_ID)): ?>
            <?php echo get_attachment_url_image_comment($comment->comment_ID) ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Result: `"http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/11439468-3x4-xlarge-2.jpg"`

It works fine!